# Android crashing while accessing adapter

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to Android.

I can get data using Socket.IO, but apparently it crashes at "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" when dynamically updating the ListActivity. Has anyone got better ideas on how to update it?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;
import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    Socket socket = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.174:10016");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    obj.put("hash", "#foo");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                socket.emit("connect_now", obj);
            }

        }).on("event", new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {}

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {}
        });

        socket.on("update_playlist", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)args[0];
                JSONArray array = null;
                try {
                    array = obj.getJSONArray("content");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                    try {
                        listItems.add(array.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        socket.connect();
    }
}
```

This, I believe, is the error I'm getting:

```
07-27 12:10:49.997    1955-1974/com.example.myapp.myapplication3 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416f7e18)
07-27 12:10:49.997    1955-1974/com.example.myapp.myapplication3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9500
    Process: com.example.myapp.myapplication3, PID: 1955
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6454)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3049)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:650)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:650)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:650)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:650)
            at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9008)
            at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:6182)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:718)
            at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:813)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6865)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
            at com.example.myapp.myapplication3.MyActivity$5.call(MyActivity.java:96)
```

Edit. added this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

and now it works. Sorry for causing trouble.

Comment: post the stack trace from the log cat, it's not that difficult. Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V

Comment: Sorry, should've thought about this right away. I'm not that proficient with the debugger. Edited the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only update `View` objects from the main, or UI, thread.

The error in the stack trace says what the problem is (although maybe it is not clear):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

We call the application's main thread the UI thread, because this is the thread that creates the views. Once you understand that, then the error makes sense.

---

In order to do an update from another thread, either use `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)` or `View.post(Runnable)`.

Comment: This can be the source of many bugs in the early stages of learning Android. It is always a good idea to try and understand what thread you may be on, and use these methods if there is any doubt.